# Strange Grassmann double integration

Tags: supersymmetry, grassmann-numbers

I can unterstand why because the integration over Grassman variables has to be translational invariant too, one has

$$
\int d\theta = 0
$$

and

$$
\int d\theta  \theta = 1
$$

but I dont see where the rule for this double integration

$$
\int d^2 \theta \bar{\theta}\theta = -2i
$$

comes from.

So can somebody explain to me how this is motivated and/or derived?

Comment: Is the last integral supposed to read something like $\int d^2\!\theta \, \bar{\theta}\theta$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As with anything that has to do with supersymmetry the details will be dependent on your exact conventions, but we can obtain the result as follows:

Assume we have two Grassman variables $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$. By applying your first formula twice we find
$$\int d\theta_1 d\theta_2 \, \theta_2 \theta_1 = 1$$
Now combine these into
$$\theta = \theta_1 + i\theta_2 \qquad \text{and} \qquad \bar{\theta}=\theta_1-i\theta_2.$$
We then have
$$\bar{\theta} \theta = - 2i\theta_2\theta_1$$
and hence
$$\int d\theta_1 d\theta_2 \bar{\theta} \theta = - 2i$$
which is exactly your second integral, if we identify the measure
$$d^2\theta = d\theta_1 d\theta_2.$$